# Can real time be used in spicy.integrate.solve_ivp?

Tags: python

I want to calculate velocity and altitude (or displacement) from acceleration.

The acceleration formula is on ODE. So using solve_ivp, I could get velocity and altitude.

The thing is that I need the solution of solve_ivp to be obtained in real-time.

From the docs:

```
scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, method='RK45', t_eval=None, dense_output=False, events=None, vectorized=False, args=None, **options
```

In t_span, we normally write [t0,t1] - where t0 and t1 are the lower and upper boundaries of the integration and they are values.
Eg. To integrate over an hour t_span would be [0,3600]

Instead can t0 = time.time() , t1 = time.time() and incorporate

```
time.sleep (5)
```

inside the solve_ivp function, maybe in t_eval, to get a solution every 5 seconds?

Down here is my code so far:

```
# Constants
Grav = 9.81
RocketMass = 1000.0 #kg                # rocket mass with no fuel
JetArea = (0.1)**2*np.pi  # m^2      # d(exhaust gases ) = 0.31 m
JetVel = 1500.0  # m/s                 # velocity of exhaust gases (jet)
C_d = 0.75
rho_air = 1.2    # kg/m^3
RocketArea = (0.31/2)**2*np.pi  # m^2  # cross-sectional A of rocket
p_atm = 101000.0 #Pa
p_jet = p_atm


def rocket(t,y):
    
    # unpack the variables
    h,u,m = y  # state of rocket
    
    # mass loss
    if m < RocketMass:
        DeltaM = 0.0 # change in rocket mass
                      # when fuel is gone, rocket does not change mass further
    else:
        DeltaM = -JetArea*JetVel  # -ve dm/dt: mass loss
        
    # acceleration -- when integrated you get velocity
    DeltaV = ((p_jet - p_atm)*(m/JetArea)) - ((JetVel/m)*DeltaM) - Grav - ((C_d * RocketArea *  rho_air * u**2)/(2 * m))
    return [u, DeltaV, DeltaM]     


# events
def ignition (t,y):
    return y[0]
ignition.terminal = False
ignition.direction = 1

def hit_ground(t, y):
    return y[0]
    # y[0] = 1st element in state --> alttitude (h)
hit_ground.terminal = True # when rocket hits the ground - integration is stopped
hit_ground.direction = -1
            
def burnout(t, y):
    return y[2]-RocketMass
    # y[2] = 3rd element in state --> mass (m)
burnout.terminal = False
burnout.direction = -1

def apogee(t, y):
    return y[1]
    # y[1] = 2nd element in state --> velocity (u)
apogee.terminal = False
apogee.direction = -1


# Launch a rocket with 1500kg of fuel and see what happens

t0 = 0
t1 = 3600


sol = solve_ivp(rocket,
                [t0, t1], # 1 hour of flight maximum
                [ 0.0, 0.0, RocketMass + 1500.0], # initial conditions
                 # [0]: alttitude [1]:initial u  [2]: initisl mass
                method = 'LSODA',# stiff ODE solver
                dense_output=True,
                events=(ignition,burnout,apogee,hit_ground))
```

I will appreciate any thoughts or improvements

Comment: You can just solve everything from the start every 5 seconds, with your added data point. If that's not an option (for example if it's too slow) then you can set the last known state as the initial condition and solve for a single time step only.

Comment: Okay. So what you mean by solving everything from the start every 5seconds is to use t_span = [0, 3600] and t_eval=t , where t = np.linspace(0,3600,720) ?                     I got 720 points by dividing 3600 by 5.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. I assumed you wanted to re-solve every 5 seconds because you've got new data (for example, steering) coming in every 5 seconds that you need to incorporate into the equation. If that's not the case, why would you want to recompute the solution more than once? It's going to be the same every time.

Comment: No. There is no new data coming in. The code is simulating the flight of a rocket. The result of solve_ivp will give the velocity, altitude and mass values of the rocket at different times. What I wanted to do (if possible) was instead of using a defined t_span, to use the current time. So when I print (sol.t) I get the real times. But maybe it is unnecessary, I don't know.